# How to have a PerWebRequest Lifestyle in all my transient dependencies using ABP?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate, .net-4.6.1

We're facing an issue in terms of performance in a .NET Framework 4.6.1 application that uses ABP 4.8.1. The detected issue is related to a continuous use of the dependency injector resolver with transient dependencies.

We were trying to change the "Lifestyle" from Transient to PerWebRequest, using Castle Windsor 
(This is the default package that ABP uses) but if we do this we keep getting this exception:

> Looks like you forgot to register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule”?

Of course we added the necessary lines, as mentioned in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34920667/12042620

The exception was thrown when we tried with a proof of concept like this:

```
public class MyModule : AbpModule
{
        public override void PreInitialize()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>());
            Configuration.DefaultNameOrConnectionString = "Default";
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            IocManager.IocContainer.Register(
                Component
                    .For<MyDbContext>()
                    .LifestylePerWebRequest()
                );
            IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
}
```

I was trying to find some other possible solutions but all of them are related to .NET Core (they use 'Scoped' instead of this). Is there any way to implement this Lifestyle for all our dependencies while using ABP?

Comment: Are you on ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: Yes @aaron I'm using MVC 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your types with `LifestylePerWebRequest` as seen here
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/e0ded5d8702f389aa1f5947d3446f16aec845287/src/Abp.Web.Mvc/Web/Mvc/Controllers/ControllerConventionalRegistrar.cs#L11

And add this registrar to the PreInitialize of your module like here
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/e0ded5d8702f389aa1f5947d3446f16aec845287/src/Abp.Web.Mvc/Web/Mvc/AbpWebMvcModule.cs#L29